# How to synchronously call multiple functions angularjs

Tags: angularjs

For example, I have four functions:

```
var f1 = function() {...};
var f2 = function() {...};
var f3 = function() {...};
var f4 = function() {...};
var fmain = function() {...};
```

The main function is a for loop:

```
  var fmain = function () {
    angular.forEach(question_list, function (question, key) {

      f3();  //I want to execute f4() after f3() is returned!

      f4();

    });

  };
```

In `f3()`, `f2()` is called!

```
var f2() = function(){
//There's a timeout function to check if the dynamic value equals to the expected value
//if so, then return true; otherwise, keep calling f2() until the dynamic value equals to the expected value
}
```

In `f2()`, `f1()` is called!

```
var f1() = function(){
//There's a timeout function to check if the dynamic value equals to the expected value
//if so, then return true; otherwise, keep calling f1() until the dynamic value equals to the expected value
}
```

So, `f3` depends on `f2`, `f2` depends on `f1`.

I want to have them return synchronously (Need the code not to proceed to next line if the previous line is not returned yet). How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless there is server (api) calls, all the functions above will be executed synchronously. Can you explain do you have any asynchronous operation there?

Comment: Use promises, the $q module in angular should help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$q` service:

```
var f1() = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function(){
        defer.resolve(f1result);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

var f2() = function(){
   var defer = $q.defer();
   f1().then(function(f1result){
         defer.resolve(f2result);
   });
   return defer.promise;
}
```

f3 function would work like f1 and f2 (defer,promise and resolve).

```
var fmain = function () {
angular.forEach(question_list, function (question, key) {
  f3().then(function(f3result){
      f4();
  });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        return A()
            .then(function (response) {
                //this portion of code in then of A() (let's call it function B) will execute only after A() provides a response or is resolved.
                if (response.isAllowed == true) {
                    otherData = myFactory.getOtherDataFromServiceOne();
                }
                else {
                    otherData = hisFactory.getOtherDataFromServiceTwo();
                }
                return $q.all([
                    otherData
                ]).then(function (results) {
                    return {
                        otherData: results[0]
                    };
                });
            });
    }


    function A() {
            var isAllowed = myFactory.isAllowed(userId);
            return $q.all([
                isAllowed 
            ]).then(function (results) {
                return {
                    isAllowed : results[0].data;
                };
            });
    };
```

I would mention here that $q.all is only being used to represent that we can pass as many functions in each of one $q.all used here otherwise you can simply use a $promise.